# Show PDF document in C# application on Raspbery Pi using Mono

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, mono, raspberry-pi

I have created a C# application that I am running on a Raspberry Pi with mono. In that application I would like to show a PDF document. Dos anyone know of a control that i can use ?
The only thing I can get to work is to convert the PDF to images and shoving them, but that is very heavy for the little raspberry Pi, so I would like to avoid that if possible.